# Python приложение не может подключиться к PostgreSQL Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

В результате выполнения команды **`docker-compose up --build`** получаю следующую ошибку:

```
web_1  | start
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "main.py", line 110, in <module>
web_1  |     main()
web_1  |   File "main.py", line 104, in main
web_1  |     app['db'] = loop.run_until_complete(init_db())
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
web_1  |     return future.result()
web_1  |   File "main.py", line 12, in init_db
web_1  |     conn = await asyncpg.connect(**DB_PARAMS)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1688, in connect
web_1  |     max_cacheable_statement_size=max_cacheable_statement_size)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 551, in _connect
web_1  |     raise last_error
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 543, in _connect
web_1  |     connection_class=connection_class)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 513, in _connect_addr
web_1  |     connector, timeout=timeout, loop=loop)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 352, in wait_for
web_1  |     return fut.result()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 776, in create_connection
web_1  |     raise exceptions[0]
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 763, in create_connection
web_1  |     yield from self.sock_connect(sock, address)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 451, in sock_connect
web_1  |     return (yield from fut)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 481, in _sock_connect_cb
web_1  |     raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed %s' % (address,))
web_1  | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('0.0.0.0', 5432)
```

Мой **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 main.py
    volumes:
      - .:/hlcup
      - ./data:/tmp/data/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Мой **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /hlcup
WORKDIR /hlcup
ADD requirements.txt /hlcup/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /hlcup/
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5432
```